# Conditional field in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like this :

```
<select>
<option class="0" selected="selected" value="">third</option>
<option value="1">first</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">second</option>
</select>  

<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="NewBranchRequest.PwrCnt" placeholder="sad">
```

i want to that when user select the first one,input must be required, if not doesnt matter .

Any idea ? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tie the dropdown to a model and use `ng-required` to conditionally require the field if the correct value has been selected.

```
<select ng-model="requireInput">
    <option selected="selected" value="">third</option>
    <option value="1">first</option>
    <option value="2">second</option>
</select>
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" 
       type="text" 
       ng-model="NewBranchRequest.PwrCnt" 
       placeholder="sad" 
       ng-required="requireInput==1">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56wt39y8/)